# php xml get data from complicated xml using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml-parsing

```
<1:1>
    <1:b/>
    <1:body>
        <1:P>
            <1:PPR></1:PPR>
            <1:r>
                <1:rPR></1:rPR>
                <1:t>text here</1:t>
            </1:r>
        </1:P>
    </1:body>
</1:1>
```

my xml looks like that, i need to get "1:t" from every "1:p"

but i am having some issues, as i cant just `$document->1:1->1:body->1:P->1:r->1:t`
because it does not like the colons

can anyone think of any way around this?
i have tried putting them in variables, but no joy...

here is what i have so far:

```
$document = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$body = "1:body";
$r = "1:r";
$t = "1:t";
foreach ($document->$body as $p) {
    echo $p->$r->$t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XML element names cannot start with a number. Your code will yield plenty of warnings, and the XML unfortunately won't be parsable.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in /Users/joelhinz/Kod/test/test.php on line 16
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <1:1> in /Users/joelhinz/Kod/test/test.php on line 16
Warning: simplexml_load_string():  ^ in /Users/joelhinz/Kod/test/test.php on line 16
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /Users/joelhinz/Kod/test/test.php on line 16
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <1:1> in /Users/joelhinz/Kod/test/test.php on line 16
Warning: simplexml_load_string():  ^ in /Users/joelhinz/Kod/test/test.php on line 16
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/joelhinz/Kod/test/test.php on line 20
```

You'll have to convert it to proper XML, or use a less finicky parser, I suppose.

Regarding the colon issue, if you get the rest to work, you could probably do `$document->{1:1}->{1:body}` etc.

Comment: i don't get a issue with the name beginning with a number, but for now i have done a replace to replace ones with "z", but the bracket idea gives me a error `syntax error, unexpected ':'`